# How to swap vectors that contain text objects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, sfml

When I try to swap two vectors, where one of the vectors contains text objects and the other is empty, I get this error:

```
6363    error C2664: 'void std::vector<mainmenu,std::allocator<_Ty>>::swap(std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<textDisplay,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'std::vector<mainmenu,std::allocator<_Ty>> &'    c:\sfml-2.3.2\sfml\main.cpp 254287

6463    IntelliSense: a reference of type "std::vector<textDisplay, std::allocator<textDisplay>> &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "std::vector<mainmenu, std::allocator<mainmenu>>"  c:\SFML-2.3.2\SFML\main.cpp 254287
```

this is an example of the kind of object that one of the vectors contains. the second vector is empty:

```
                    textDisplayMainmenu1.text.setString("Broadsword");
                    textDisplayMainmenu1.text.setPosition(positionX, positionY1);
                    textDisplayMainmenuVector1.push_back(textDisplayMainmenu1);
```

When I try to call the swap member function like so I get the above error:

```
textDisplayVector2.swap(mainmenu1.textDisplayMainmenuVector1);
```

Why isn't this working? What can I do to make it work?

Comment: You can't swap two vectors with different type.

Comment: what do you mean? what determines their type?

Comment: As error message said, `vector<textDisplay>` vs `vector<mainmenu>`.

Comment: I see. thank you that answers my original question

Comment: if you answer as an official answer i'll choose best

Comment: that actually solves everything, the answer was so simple all along